# Extracting a Calendar Year from Tax Year using R

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, extract

Year    Winner
2019-2020   100
2019-2020   500
2019-2020   10000
2020-2021   100559
2020-2021   114431
2020-2021   121461
2021-2022   200233

I have a dataset similar to the above, am seeking help onn how to extract a calendar year from the fiscal year using R

Comment: What is your expected outcome?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to extract the first (or second) part of the year column to get a cal_yr column like this? Or have I misunderstood the question?

```r
library(tidyverse)

tribble(
  ~year, ~winner,
  "2019-2020", 100,
  "2019-2020", 500,
  "2019-2020", 10000,
  "2020-2021", 100559,
  "2020-2021", 114431,
  "2020-2021", 121461,
  "2021-2022", 200233
) |> 
  mutate(cal_yr = str_remove(year, "-.*"))
#> # A tibble: 7 × 3
#>   year      winner cal_yr
#>   <chr>      <dbl> <chr> 
#> 1 2019-2020    100 2019  
#> 2 2019-2020    500 2019  
#> 3 2019-2020  10000 2019  
#> 4 2020-2021 100559 2020  
#> 5 2020-2021 114431 2020  
#> 6 2020-2021 121461 2020  
#> 7 2021-2022 200233 2021
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>